# AFNetworking 2.0 - using a subclass or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

So I have been working with `AFNetworking 2.0` for the last few days and things have been going well - starting to understand the library the more I used it.

Yesterday I realised I was building a class to handle the Web Services of my app - `GET / POST /DELETE`, etc.

Now, AFNetworking already handles these things and there is no reason to build my own method. However this is the part I am getting stuck on.

Here is a brief example of what I want to do:

In a `DataStore` type of class I would like to do something like this:

**RCBaseDataStore.h**

```
-(void)handelWebService: (int) webServiceID 
{

    Switch (webServiceID) 

    case: GET_STORE_ITEMS_WSID 
    {
       BBWebService *newService = [[BBWebService alloc]initWithURL:URL 
                                                       RequestType:@"GET" 
                                                       PostDataValuesAndKeys:nil 
                                                       RequestProperties:nil 
                                                       UrlParameters:urlParams];
    } 

}
```

In the above - I used a index of Web Service ID's - this allows be to use a switch statement - but there are 30 or 40 web services - so this method would grow.. a lot.

What I now need to do is get the `BBWebService` to act on that URL - which then builds the URL and puts the parameters together - I then hand that off to another method inside `BBWebService` that runs the `GET / POST requests`

The problems I am facing:

1. AFNetworking does all this (Building the URL and running the request) - How do I use the methods it uses - without re-defining them but rather just adding to them?

For example `GET / POST requests` - I need to store the `responseObject` in a `NSData object` which I can do. But I don't want this logic in the `RCBaseDataStore` - I want it in `BBWebService` - but without overriding methods in `AfNetworking` super class that I would find the original methods in.

I looked in `AFRequestSteralization.h` file in the AFNetworking library and it has a protocol as:

```
 (NSURLRequest *)requestBySerializingRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                               withParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                                        error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error;
```

In the notes it says this:

> Returns a request with the specified parameters encoded into a copy
>   of the original request.
>
> @param request The original request.  @param parameters The
>   parameters to be encoded.  @param error The error that occurred while
>   attempting to encode the request parameters.
>
> @return A serialized request.

Now would I make BBWebService conform to this protocol and then in RCBaseData Store have the method for doing a request, done differently - for `GET / POST`?

The first argument is what I am not sure about - how do I create a `NSURLRequest` object for a `GET /POST request`?

Once I make the request - how do I then get `BBWebService` to *capture* the response?

As I am typing this out I am thinking... make two classes, one a response and one a request?  I think I am almost at the solution I need to be at - just need to clear the path though.

Answer (score 2):

Not to do that anymore.

No Subclass anymore

You should create 'own class' and use AFHTTPOperationManager

That pretty much it.

Comment: I'd like to use AFHTTPSessionManager instead for all networking stuff as the app will be iOS7 only. (NSURLSession can be used). The problem if in another class - how do I detect between POST /GET - requests, without writing a massive IF statement in a method of "Own Class" ? - Will using AFNetworking's protocols work for this instead? Here http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Protocols/AFURLResponseSerialization.html and this one: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Protocols/AFURLRequestSerialization.html    Thanks for the help!